# Reformat Twitter Bootstrap menu when making it smaller

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not sure if the current headline is the best but I couldnøt come up with anything better.

I have this menu (the black/inverse line):

[image]

When I resize my menu it makes it into a list format with the menu 1 as header:

[image]

I do not want this list view so how can I make it work alike the bottom line where it just reformats the text to a new line?

My code:

```
<div class="mymenu navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">My Project</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu4" data-toggle="tab">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu5" data-toggle="tab">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu6" data-toggle="tab">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu7" data-toggle="tab">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu8" data-toggle="tab">Menu 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu9" data-toggle="tab">Menu 9</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have a Fiddle for it here, http://jsfiddle.net/G5N67/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by this rule :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

You can simply override it for `width < 768px`, by adding those rules to your CSS :

```
/* The one your looking for */
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left; 
}
/* Other rules for visual issues */
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

[image]

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/G5N67/2/)